# Having the user search a text file inside an array for a name, and then printing the shortest and longest names in the file

Tags: java, arrays

The code I'm writing is to have the user search a name in a text file and, if the name is found in the file, then the program will output "Name found."

Then I just need the program to output the shortest and longest name in the file which is plainly something I have no idea how to do. This is what I have so far and I just can't get it to work.

Just want to be clear that programming is not my strong suit so my code may be a little sloppy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Homework11 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // resets the Scanner to look for commas as
        // the separator between the color names
        fileScan.useDelimiter(",");

        // initial capacity by default is 10 items
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {

            // each color read from the file is added to the ArrayList
            names.add(fileScan.next());
        }

        // dump all the color names into a standard array of Strings
        String namesArray[] = names.toArray(new String[0]);

        // sort the color array into alphabetical order
        Arrays.sort(namesArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {

            // copy the array values back, overwriting the ArrayList
            names.set(i, namesArray[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter a name to search.");
        String input = keyboard.next();
        String x = input.toUpperCase();
        if (names.contains(x)) {
            System.out.println("Name Found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might like to have a look at `Collections.sort` and save having to "rebuild" the `ArrayList`...

Comment: How does the `name` length differ?  Either they will be equal or they won't be

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet right before your for loop:

```
//set the default values
int longLength = namesArray[0].length;
int shortLength = namesArray[0].length;
String longName = namesArray[0];
String shortName = namesArray[0]; 

//check if any element is better than the current best
for (int i=1; i < namesArray.length; i++) { 
    if(namesArray[i].length > longLength){
        longLength = namesArray[i].length;
        longName = namesArray[i];
    }
    if(namesArray[i].length < shortLength){
        shortLength = namesArray[i].length;
        shortName = namesArray[i];
    }
}
```

Then, you can output the longest/shortest names by outputting longName/shortName.